# Removing custom taxonomy base slug causing 404 error on other pages

Tags: wordpress, custom-taxonomy

I have created a custom taxonomy with the following code given below. I want to remove taxonomy base slug. When I pass 'hierarchical' => true in rewrite it causes 404 error on other pages.

Anyone can help?

```
register_taxonomy(
        'blog-categories',
        'blog',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => 'Categories',
                'add_new_item' => 'Add Blog Category',
                'new_item_name' => "New Blog Category"
            ),
    'has_archive' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
        'hierarchical' => true,
    'rewrite' => array('hierarchical' => true, 'slug' => '/', 'with_front' => false),
        )
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add a slash, that will likely not help the 404.

Also you have two hierarchical lines, just try:

```
'rewrite' => array('slug' => ''),
```

Also when you save the changes remember to save permalinks or flush re-write rules.